# attaching an email message to an email rails 2.3.5 upgrading to rails 3.017

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

In rails 2.3.5 we were able to attach emails as attachments to other emails which were multipart emails using the following code:

```
 recipients to
   from       from
   subject    subject
   content_type "multipart/mixed" 

   part "text/html" do |p| 
     p.body = render_message("rampup_notification.text.html.erb", :mailbody => body)  
   end 

   part "text/plain" do  |p| 
     p.body = render_message("rampup_notification.text.plain.erb", :mailbody => body) 
   end 

    email = enrollment_application.email
   if email != nil && email.raw_email != nil
     attachment :content_type => "message/rfc822", :filename => "icann.eml", :body => email.raw_email, :transfer_encoding => '7bit'
   end
```

This was very temperamental to get to work with outlook, exchange etc along with other mailers.

How do I do this in rails 3?

I see:  http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.0.0/ActionMailer/Base:attachments

```
 encoded_content = SpecialEncode(File.read('/path/to/filename.jpg'))
 attachments['filename.jpg'] = {:mime_type => 'application/x-gzip',
                           :encoding => 'SpecialEncoding',
                           :content => encoded_content }
```

But I dont understand how to use this, is SpecialEncode a class I need to write that does 7bit encoding?

thanks
Joel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out rails 3 actionmailer is pretty smart, this seems to work fine:

```
@mailbody = body
attachments["icann.eml"] = {:content => email.raw_email }
mail(:to => to, :from => from, :subject => subject)
```